# Unable to display "Marathi" characters on a PHP website

Tags: php, html, css, content-management-system

I am trying to rebuild a website for a client which was deleted with malicious intent. This website is a CMS developed in PHP. There are some links in the website which are stored in "Marathi language" in a database. I am able to display the page with the links but unfortunately, I am not able to display the "Marathi" characters. Instead the website displays "?????" .

I have downloaded MANGAL.TTF font from the net. I have stored this in fonts directory in CSS and I have defined a font-face as follows

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MANGAL";
    src: url("css/fonts/MANGAL.TTF");
    }
```

Also, I have added "MANGAL" to the font-family of * as

```
* { 
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif, 'MANGAL';
     font-size: 12px;
}
```

Unfortunately, I am still not able to see the links in "Marathi".

I guess, I am making some mistake. Can someone please advise?

Thanks

Sachin

Comment: encoding issue maybe ?

Comment: UTF-8 is capable with Marathi characters, so my guess would be database problem...

Comment: @Dekel - I can clearly see the words in "Marathi" in the table, so, it does not seem to be a database problem. Do you have any other suggestions? Is there something which I have missed in the code above?

Comment: which table? what are you talking about?

Comment: @Calimero - Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Dekel - The links and the html are stored in a database as this is a CMS. I am referring to that table. Were you not referring to the same when you mentioned a database problem?

Comment: where it is written? what is this table? the name of the column? the charset? the collate? I have no idea what you are talking about..

Comment: I would begin with checking encodings everywhere I can - cms, html, server configuration and database, if relevant to what you are doing. I can't explain all of those in a comment, so run your google searches acordingly. It's a common thing to do for those of us who are native to non-english speaking countries. UTF-8 everywhere is probably good (although I can't say for sure with Marathi specifically), better be sure though.

Comment: Hi, I have found the solution to my problem. Before running the select statement on the database , I ran this command                                  
$result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); This ensured that the characters which were in marathi in my tables were displayed in marathi on the website. Thanks for all the help.